# Windows Phone 8 : "The drive cannot locate a specific area or track on the disk."

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I get following message when I try to add "Periodic Task" to "ScheduledActionService" in Windows Phone 8 Application.

"The drive cannot locate a specific area or track on the disk."

I am really not sure if this is related to Visual Studio 2012 that I am using or related to Periodic Tasks on Windows Phone 8.

The same piece of code works fine in Windows Phone 7.

Comment: This is missing context. Do "hello world" type apps work in your emulator? What code snippet specifically fails?

Comment: ScheduledActionService.Add(periodicTask); is the piece of code that throws this exception...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wpdevelop/thread/a973955e-0981-4be8-8ac0-8dfcb9dc2917/

You need to manually update your WPAppManifest.xml file and configure the background task there.

Appears to be normal behavior, not related to emulator or debugging.

Answer (score 3):

There is a excellent explanation as to what is required by microsoft for background task in the msdn tutorial videos.

It references your problem at around 24:30 with editing the WPAppManifest.xml file.
He explains step by step what needs to be done and why.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-34-Creating-a-Background-Agent-for-Scheduled-Tasks

Also I got a null reference exception after fixing the WPAppManifest.xml when called from the the main project, turns out the main project also has to reference the scheduler project (even if not using anything in it).

Comment: Thanks for noting this additional pitfall.  MSFT was not on the ball when documenting ScheduledAgents!

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the ScheduledTaskAgent as a Reference to the main project.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the WPDT Notes

Runtime exception occurs when an application attempts to use a launcher/chooser in Microsoft.Phone.Tasks to call an application that is not present in the Emulator home screen. The following error string is displayed, “The drive cannot locate a specific area or track on the disk.” Workaround: Do not use the launcher/chooser or catch this exception.

http://download.microsoft.com/download/d/9/2/d926fb38-bb43-4d87-ae5a-1a3391279fac/releasenotes.htm.

(PS If you can't view the link Google "Windows Phone Developer Tools CTP Release Notes")